# Inline assembly loop doesn't update memory

Tags: solidity, assembly, memory

I want to copy in inline assembly from calldata the last two bytes of every 32 byte slices to the lower half of the first free memory slot(32 bytes).

free = free memory pointer + 14 (bytes)

moffset = free + (loop count * 2) so in the first run calldatacopy copy the bytes at the start of the lower half of the 32 byte slot

loffset = 4 + (loop count * 30) the first four bytes are the function signature, and i want copy from the calldata the data what follows the signature, and the data is packed by 32 bytes, and i want to read starting from the (loop number * 30th byte)

When i debug it in RemixIDE the memory location is not updated after the first loop.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract YourContract {
mapping (address=>uint128) public whitelist;

function _setwlistA(uint16[8] calldata partitions, address operator) public {
 assembly{
   let i:=1
   let free:= add(mload(64),14)
   for {} lt (i,9) {} 
     {
      let moffset := add(free,mul(i,2))
      let loffset := add(4,mul(i,30))
      calldatacopy(moffset,loffset,2)
      i := add(i,1)
      }
   mstore(0,operator)
   mstore(32, whitelist.slot)
   sstore(keccak256(0,64),mload(sub(free,14)))
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While i was editing my question i realized:

I just need to set the offset for calldata's reading point first to 34 outside the loop, then in every loop i must add 32 to it.

outside:

```
let loffset:= 34
```

inside:

```
loffset := add(loffset,32)
```